Missing metric replaced by 0 PromQL Grafana
I have multiple metrics that are scraped using Prometheus and shown in Grafana. They all have the same labels.Ex:
metric1(currency=CURR1,application=APP1,env=ENV).

For certain currencies I have multiple metrics and for others I have only one. Ex:
metric1(currency=CURR1,application=APP1,env=ENV),
metric1(currency=CURR2,application=APP1,env=ENV),
metric1(currency=CURR3,application=APP2,env=ENV),
metric2(currency=CURR1,application=APP1,env=ENV),
metric3(currency=CURR1,application=APP1,env=ENV)

I am trying to do certain arithmetic operations with the metrics in Grafana, such as (metric1 - (metric2 + metric3)) / metric1. For CURR1 it works, as I have all the metrics. For CURR2 and 3 it doesn't because I am missing either metric2 and metric3 or both. This is a simplified version of my setup.
I tried to use or vector(0) for all metrics, but it still doesn't show the result only if all metrics exist. Ex:
(metric1 - ((metric2 or vector(0)) + (metric3 or vector(0)) / metric1 -> this will only print the result for CURR1
I also tried using or clamp_max(absent(notExists{currency=CURR1, env=ENV, application=APP1),0)
If for CURR2 I only have metric1, I want the calculation to be made and show the result 1. I am displaying the data as a table in Grafana.

or vector(0) doesn't work for series with labels.
Working with non full sets of data is rather tricky, and it better to avoid direct operations if possible.
Let me point out that (metric1 - (metric2 + metric3)) / metric1 is equivalent to 2 - (metric1 + metric2 + metric3) / metric1. This means that we can avoid direct addition by employing sum.
2 - sum by (currency,application,env) ({__name__=~"metric1|metric2|metric3"}) / metric1
Here:

{__name__=~"metric1|metric2|metric3"} takes all metrics with name metric1, metric2 or metric3,
sum by (currency,application,env) aggregates them within same values of listed labels

